# Inheritance. Polymorphism. Abstractization

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm working on a testing platform app for students. Since the question can have one or multiple correct answers, I need radio buttons/checkboxes for selecting the right one(s). I would like to implement an abstract class with an Add method. From it, derive two classes, each of them containing an array of `RaddioButton`s or `Checkbox`es. Is there a better way to do this than the one listed below? I mean, can the add method be put in the abstract class?

```
public class AnswerForm
    {
        public static int no;

        public AnswerForm()
        {
            no=0;
        }
    }

    public class RadioButtonClass:AnswerForm
    {
        RadioButton[] vector;

        public void Add(RadioButton rbutton)
        {
            vector[no++] = rbutton;
        }
    }

    public class CheckBoxClass : AnswerForm
    {
        CheckBox[] vector;

        public void Add(CheckBox cbox)
        {
            vector[no++] = cbox;
        }
    }
```

I also have two vectors in which I put a fixed number of elements, RadioButtons and Checkboxes. These elements exist in the Windows Form `Form1.cs[design]`. What I would like to do is pass one an element of type AnswerForm to a function and in the function, based on what type of question I have, allocate memory to my AnswerForm object for one of the derived classes. Also, it might be easier if the Add method would have as parameter a `s` string, and `vector[no++].Text=s`;

The prototype of the function:

```
public void readQuestions(RichTextBox richTextBox, AnswerForm answerForm)
```

Here I'm parsing an XML file and put the objects in a List. The `XML` contains `Questions`, each having a type(multiple or single answer), the text which goes to the `richTextBox`, and the answers. Next i'm looping through the question list and check question's type. If multiple answers, then put each answer in a `CheckBox.Text`. Else, put it in a `RadioButton.Text`. Before assigning the text to each WinForm element, I would like to allocate the corresponding object type(RadioButtonClass or CheckBoxClass) and then use the add method for each answer of the current question. That is why I thought of inheritance, abstractization an polymorphism.

This is how it look like now:

```
public void readQuestions(RichTextBox richTextBox, AnswerForm answerForm)
        {
            var file = XDocument.Load("QuestionsTest.xml");
            var subject = new Subject();
            subject.Name = (string)file.Root.Attribute("Subject");

            var questions = from question in file.Root.Elements("Question")
                            select new Question
                            {
                                NumberOfCorrectAnswers=(int)question.Attribute("NumberOfAnswers"),
                                Text = (string)question.Element("Text"),
                                Answers = new List<Answer>(
                                    from answers in question.Element("Answers").Elements("Answer")
                                    select new Answer
                                    {
                                        Text = (string)answers
                                    })
                            };

            using (var db = new TestingPlatformContext())
            {
                db.Subjects.Add(subject);

                foreach (var question in questions)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\n Text: {1}", question.Subject, question.Text);
                    richTextBox.Text = question.Text;
                    //db.Questions.Add(question);
                    foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
                        //Console.WriteLine("Answer: {0}", answer.Text);
                        if (question.NumberOfCorrectAnswers != 1)
                        {
                            answerForm = new CheckBoxClass();
                            answerForm.Add(answer.Text);
                            //db.Answers.Add(answer);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            answerForm = new RadioButtonClass();
                            answerForm.Add(answer.Text);
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I would suspect that a single Form should be able to handle different types of questions; having the CheckBox(es) directly as part of the "Form" is likely a limiting design - it also doesn't seem to capture the Question aspect.

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation for how is that limiting the design? And what do you mean by capturing the Question aspect? The question will be bound to a RichTextBox if that is what you are reffering to, so it has nothing to do with these classes.

Comment: A Form contains Questions, a Question contains the details about such a question (including perhaps the UI display, although would isolate a Question from the Display of a question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can move the Add() method to parent class, using generic:

```
public class AnswerForm<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> _list;

    public AnswerForm()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T button)
    {
        _list.Add(button);
    }
}

public class RadioButtonClass:AnswerForm<RadioButton>
{
}

public class CheckBoxClass : AnswerForm<CheckBox>
{
}
```

I made a few changes:
- Use list instead of array, it's more flexible in this case
- Use generic in parent class AnswerForm

Comment: I also tried the generic classes approach, but because I want a `AnswerForm` object to be passed as parameter to a function, this does not work due to `Using the generic type requires 1 type arguments`

Comment: could you give some code example of the function that AnswerForm needs to be passed to and what you are doing inside that? It's a bit difficult to imagine from the description

Comment: I explained what the function does. Hope it is clear now. I also provided the code.

Answer (score 0):

A solution, much simple, would be like this:

```
public class AnswerForm
        {
            public static int no;
            private RadioButton[] rbuttons;
            private Checkbox[] checkboxes;

            public AnswerForm()
            {
                no=0;
                rbuttons = new RadioButton[] 
                {
                    radioButton1,radioButton2,radioButton3,radioButton4,radioButton5
                };
                checkboxes = new CheckBox[]
                {
                    checkBox1,checkBox2,checkBox3,checkBox4,checkBox5,checkBox6
                };
            }
            public void AddRadio(string s)
            {
                rbuttons[no++].Text=s;
            }
            public void AddBox(string s)
            {
                checkboxes[no++].Text=s;
            }
        }
```

But this is far from elegant.

Comment: Might be even better than what I was looking for.